# Error while hosting a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, hosting

I just created a simple web application project to learn how to host your website.

Following things that I have done so far:

1. Managed to create a free hosting space on somee.com
2. Uploading all the files in my project via file manager option.

That was all I could figure out that I had to do.

Now when I try to open the Index page I get the following error message

"Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TestingHosting.Index'."
Then there is further detail of the message.

> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
>   CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestingHosting.Index" %> 
>   Line 2: 
>   Line 3:

I haven't hosted any web page \ website in ASP.Net before so I am certainly missing some important step.

The web page is working fine on my computer but it's like I cannot make it run on internet. I hope that I am clear and maybe it is a common thing with newbie to hosting.

A lot of thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: stop everything, clean and rebuild

Comment: Thanks raj but that didn't work :(